Strange WPF Data Validation behaviour
The class TabItemEx is inherited from TabItem with an extra int property to record the number of Validation Errors raised from Controls under it.
internal class TabItemEx : TabItem, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private int _NumErrors;
    public int NumErrors
    {
        get => _NumErrors;
        set
        {
            if (_NumErrors != value)
            {
                _NumErrors = value;
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(NumErrors)));
            }
        }
    }

    public TabItemEx() : base()
    {
        NumErrors = 0;
        Debug.WriteLine("TabItemEx Created");
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

The Count of Validation Errors was updated each time the Validation.Error routed event fired.
private void CollectError(object sender, ValidationErrorEventArgs e)
{
    var tabItemEx= sender as TabItemEx;
    if (tabItemEx == null) return;
    if (e.Action == ValidationErrorEventAction.Added)
    {
        tabItemEx.NumErrors++;

        Debug.WriteLine($"{tabItemEx.Header.ToString()}:+:{tabItemEx.NumErrors} {e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString()}");
    }
    else
    {
        tabItemEx.NumErrors--;
        Debug.WriteLine($"{tabItemEx.Header.ToString()}:-:{tabItemEx.NumErrors} {e.Error.ErrorContent.ToString()}");
    }

if (tabItemEx.NumErrors == 0)
{
    tabItemEx.Foreground = Brushes.Black;
}
else 
{
    tabItemEx.Foreground = Brushes.Red;
}

This works fine when load an instance without any Validation Errors in its initial states. (To reproduce, click Normal button after start-up) . The Validation rules are: all the three int properties A, B, C should be larger than zero.
What's strange is that when loading an instance with an improper initial A value right after the application setting up, the number of collected validation errors becomes zero.


At this state, changing A from -2 to 2 would produce meaningless negative counts.

Here is a ready-to-run minimal VS project for quick reproduction.
Could anyone explain why these happen? And more importantly, how to get the correct error number when loading an instance with initial validation errors?

The first time loading the  datatemplate seems to not fire Validation.Error

The order of execution at the first time was:
TabItem Created-> TabItem ContentChanged->Validation in ViewModel Class->TabItem ApplyTemplate->TabItem Loaded.
There is no Validation.Error event fired.

Is there any easy way to get the correct number of errors?

Sorry but I don't know how to solve this.

You'd better do all validation and grouping in view model. DO NOT  TRY TO BREAK THE BASIC PRICIPLE OF WPF
